# Adding Mr/Ms/Mrs to a signature

Tags: politeness, email, letter-writing, honorifics

Suppose one has an unusual or foreign name, or a name which traditionally belongs to the other gender. Is it inappropriate to add one's title (i.e. Mr/Ms/Mrs) to the signature of a letter/email so as to identify the author's gender?

Comment: Define "*appropriate*".

Answer (score 2):

If this is a formal letter or e-mail between you and someone (ex. you and a teacher or an employer), it would definitely be correct to add the title before the name.

Comment: As in, "Respectfully Yours, Mr. Ioannes Doeus." That'll teach them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. You shouldn't. Don't. It would be silly and impolite. People would throw garbage at you.

You could use a trick or two, though. You could insert a nickname between the Christian name and surname. As in:

Sincerely Yours,
Laballa "Gentlemanly Jack" Barocca, Esq.

or

Affectionately Yours,
Drapezhnik "Bubbly Jill" Femistodinzs

Comment: In a formal context I don't think adding a nickname is appropriate. In an informal context, it might be,  but they are more likely to already know your gender so it's almost a moot point.

Comment: @LiamNoronha: The point is not moot. It can't be moot. It shouldn't be moot. The question was, Is it inappropriate to ... etc.

Comment: It is far more impolite to add a nickname than it is to preface your name with its proper honorific. I disagree not only with your proposed work around,  but with your answer as well. Including the honorific is acceptable.

Comment: @LiamNoronha: You have every right to disagree with me. It would never occur to me to dispute it.